# Function stops after jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, hide, each

I have this function:

```
function accentFold(inStr) {
    return inStr.replace(/([àáâãäå])|([ç])|([èéêë])|([ìíîï])|([ñ])|([òóôõöø])|([ß])|([ùúûü])|([ÿ])|([æ])/g,
                          function(str,a,c,e,i,n,o,s,u,y,ae) { 
                              if(a) return 'a'; 
                              else if(c) return 'c'; 
                              else if(e) return 'e'; 
                              else if(i) return 'i'; 
                              else if(n) return 'n';
                              else if(o) return 'o'; 
                              else if(s) return 's'; 
                              else if(u) return 'u'; 
                              else if(y) return 'y'; 
                              else if(ae) return 'ae'; 
                           });
}

function checkResults(searchString) {
    jQuery('.swiper-slide').each(function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var valorname = currentElement.find("p").html();
        var valornamelatin = accentFold(valorname);
        var searchResult = valorname.match(searchString, "i");
        var searchResultLatin = valornamelatin.match(searchString, "i");

        if (searchResult != null || searchResultLatin != null){
            currentElement.show();
            countResults ++;
        } else {
            currentElement.hide();
        }
        swiperCatego01.reInit();
    });

    alert ("One Alert");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#friendsSearch').keyup(function(){
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        var countResults = "0";
        checkResults(searchString);

        alert(countResults);

        if (countResults == 0) {
            $('#nohayCoincidencias').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#nohayCoincidencias').hide();
            swiperCatego01.reInit();
        }
    });

})
```

What this function does is it searchs on a list of people for the matching names trough an input text box. The functions works properly hiding the names that doesn't contain the searched criteria, but the odd thing is that I can get anithing done after the .each() function, I'm not that good with jQUery and I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong, I can't make the alert to work or anything else whatsoever.

Example in:

http://design.rankon.me/appdesign/invitetemplate.php

Edit:

It's actually working on Google Chrome but fails to work on Safari of iPhone wich is my final destination, so the solution must work on Safari on ios6 +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared countResults inside a keyup function, so its only declared inside that scope. So it throws error when you try to do

```
countResults ++;
```

You should declare the variable as global one above all functions:

```
 var countResults = "0";
```

Comment: You're right, except that your variable wont' be global right there either, so the `checkResults` won't be able to see it unless you move `checkResults` inside the `.ready()` callback.

Comment: True, hadn't noticed he had those functions outside the .ready() callback. Edited

Comment: That's great, so this is what i did to solve it, I made the check inside the .each() loop with a variable inside the loop, so it ended up like this: [link](http://design.rankon.me/appdesign/invitetemplate.php). Thanks guys @cookie monster @juvian! It worked perfect.